# Reproducing SimpleDateFormat non-thread safety in tests

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have an application which from time to time has this stacktrace in logs:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 514
        at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:436)
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2081)
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:1996)
        at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:1312)
        at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:1093)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:917)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:824)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:796)
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
        at me.myself.i.Message.toString(Message.java:203)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2615)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:116)
```

I think the problem might be somewhere in those lines:

```
public class Message{
private transient DateFormat logDateFormat;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(getClass().getSimpleName());
        result.append("Time=").append(logDateFormat.format(new Date(getExpireTime())));     
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I think multiple threads call toString() at the same time, but i have a trouble reproducing this on my local machine:

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    message = new Message();
    pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);
 }

  @Test
  public void multiThreadTest() {
        for (int i=0; i<numOfThreads; i++) {
            TestJob j = new TestJob(message);
            pool.submit(j);
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        while(!pool.isTerminated()){            
        }
    }

    class TestJob implements Runnable{

        private Message message;
        private int n=100;

        public TestJob(Message message) {
            this.message= message;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                try{
                    System.out.println(message.toString());
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do i write correct junit test to reproduce this issue?

Comment: There is no guarentee that you can reproduce a thread safety bug.  For might find that on one machine the bug never occurs and on another with different hardware it happens all the time.  I might not happen on one version of Java but suddenly appear when you upgrade when the bug has always been there.

Comment: In "result.append(Time=).append(logDateFormat.format(new Date(getExpireTime())));" what is Time= ?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` (and possibly others) is *not* thread safe. - You should definitely make sure you don't use it in multiple threads in the first place, exception or not.

Comment: `Time=` would be supposed to be `"Time="` :)

Comment: To change code in my application, first i need to reproduce this bug somehow

Comment: If you are not properly synchronizing the uses of the `DateFormat` this already *is* a bug - reproducible or not. The [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) tell us so: "Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally."

Comment: i fully understand this, but i NEED to write a test to reproduce this issue, this is what my question is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since my first test did not reproduce your problem, try this one

```
final SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
for (;;) {
    ex.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                f.format(new Date(new Random().nextLong()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

it took time but finally I got

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3144942
    at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:454)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2333)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2248)
    at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:1560)
    at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:1162)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:1093)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:978)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:948)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:336)
    at Test1$1.run(Test1.java:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date` for some reason :(

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your test:

- each thread only executes the tested method 100 times which should be increased to increase the number of thread interleaving scenarios
- you call `System.out.println` which is synchronized => you are resynchronizing your code which might remove problems

Also note that SimpleDateFormat uses a synchronized StringBuffer internally so getting a concurrent problem is not that easy.

You could:

- use a CountDownLatch to start all the threads at the same time and increae interleaving
- remove the print statement
- have each job run the tested method many times

Comment: Your first point isn't correct (there is a loop), very good point on the System.out.println(). The result doessn't need to be used in the test case. Increasing the number of iterations will help probably.

Answer (score 2):

The general way of testing for threadsafety (and performance) is to just try many times. This conflicts with the sense that unit tests should be reproducible (meaning each run has the same result). Reason for this is that chance is involved, in case of thread safety a lot.

In order for the testcase to fail on exception, each thread that calls `toString()` should catch the exception and fail (A junit function) if one is throw.

```
try{
    //do stuff
catch(RuntimeException exception){
    fail();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

100 times is highly unlikely to be enough. I suggest at least 10,00 and using more threads than you have cpus to overload the machine. e.g. 32 threads on a machine with 8 cpus.

No matter how long you run it for you cannot determine the code is thread safe by testing as you can only determine that you failed to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Try my test,

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final Date d1 = f.parse("2001-01-01");
        final Date d2 = f.parse("2012-12-12");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            final int j = i;
            new Thread() {

                void test(String s, Date expected) throws ParseException {
                    //synchronized (Test1.class) {
                        Date d = f.parse(s);
                        if (!d.equals(expected)) {
                            System.out.println(d + " != " + expected);
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    //}
                }

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (j % 2 == 0) {
                            test("2001-01-01", d1);
                        } else {
                            test("2012-12-12", d2);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                };
            }.start();
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Evgeniy, this fails but with different stacktrace from mine. Could you somehow натянуть your test for my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `for` loops with `while(true)` and wait for some time.

Comment: Isn't the exception an unwanted effect?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of properly synchronizing for the possible bug *not* to occur, one might synchronize to *produce* the bug, like:

Create multiple threads:

```
while(...)
    synchronized(sync) {
        sync.wait();
    }
    toString();
}
```

then call `sync.notifyAll()`. This *may* increase the chance of seeing the issue.